# How to make a question generator based on pdf files using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, pdf-generation

I have many mathematics worksheets like this.[image: Image of worksheet page.](This is an image of a page of pdf)
So I want to make a Python program to take questions from these worksheets **randomly** and save them to a pdf file.
I can easily take out the whole text from pdf but I have no idea how to distinguish the questions and the bigger problem is of the expression to be evaluated as they are the images of equations and not in LATEX form, that's the only problem and I will manage anything other than that (e.g. saving the questions to the pdf,etc.).
Note: I am not asking for the code itself rather I am asking for the hint/idea for extracting questions.
Thank you for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe start with a sentence paraphraser coupled with machine learning model that takes symbolics to its written language form. Once you have that you can use a keyword frequency distribution to have it scrape the web. The returned average question now paraphrased and condensed to its general relative concept would give a new question that seeks to give the best proof of understanding by randomly selecting from these general new questions the AI has bagged. If you want just random questions selected with answers verbatim, then same process just take out paraphrase parser and rely on scraping with a randomized selection function. If I totally missed the ball let me know but if not hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Been a while since.
However current suggestion would be to use that old cliche a mathematics spreads sheet. For simpler cases you can define print areas and set up random outputs via some VBA/Python formula.

Nice thing is it has equation editors or use online snips recognition for math.

[image]